# Fetch the data when compare the time

Tags: php, html, tags

I am working on a function to connect to the site for each day so I can fetch the data I want. I want to find the time in the html source to match with my current time so after that I want fetch the data.

Here is the code:

```
function get_shows($channel_id, $day, $skip_finished = true) 
{
   global $day;

   $url = 'http://example.com/api/GS?cid=' . $channel_id . '&offset=+00.00&day=' .$day;

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    ));

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // create domdocument from html retrieved
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the output for the $html:

```
["<a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:00 pm' <i class=\"c-icon c-8\" >
</i> UEFA Europa League Highlights </h2> <h3>Highlights of all matches in the UEFA Europa League.
<span  >7.0</span></h3></a><a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:30 pm' <h2><i class=\"c-icon c-8\" >
</i> UEFA Europa League Highlights </h2> <h3>Highlights of all matches in the UEFA Europa League.<span  >7.0</span></a>"]
```

If my current time show 18:30, I want to find the time `6:30 pm` in the html source to match it or greater than so I can fetch the data that start `6:30 pm` to go all the way to the end but I have got no idea how to do this.

Can you please show me an example how I can find the time using with $xpath query so I can fetch the data I want using with the html tags?

**EDIT:**

Here is for example:

If my time show 6:30 pm then I want to fetch the tag to make it display like this:

```
6:30 pm

UEFA Europa League Highlights
Highlights of all matches in the UEFA Europa League.
```

Comment: can we do this in javascript on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite sure what you're asking.  you can implode and explode a number of times to get the segment you're looking for.

```
$html = ["<a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:00 pm' <i class=\"c-icon c-8\" >
</i> UEFA Europa League Highlights </h2> <h3>Highlights of all matches in the UEFA Europa League.
<span  >7.0</span></h3></a><a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:30 pm' <h2><i class=\"c-icon c-8\" >
</i> UEFA Europa League Highlights </h2> <h3>Highlights of all matches in the UEFA Europa League.<span  >7.0</span></a>"];

$htotal=implode("<a",$html);
$harray=explode("'6:30 pm'",$htotal);
$hhalf = $harray[count($harray)-1];
$hspecific = explode("</a",$hhalf);

echo $hspecific[0];
```

will give you:

```
<h2><i class="c-icon c-8" >
</i> UEFA Europa League Highlights </h2> <h3>Highlights of all matches in 
the UEFA Europa League.<span  >7.0</span>
```

if that's actually what you are looking for I would explode on 'data-time=' and then do a substr search for the time you want in a loop through the array.  I think that's cleaner and easier to follow

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I want to know how I can fetch the `</a>` tags using with curl as you have only put the html source in the variable??

Comment: Hi, I don't know curl and not exactly sure what you are asking.  It seems you're getting the entire page back in $html. Although it seems to be coming back as an array.  You can implode that to string and then explode on <a to get an array with each of the <a tags  Does that work for you?

Comment: No it didnt work for me as I have to use `$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');` to get the content. I want to fetch the text the tags between `</i>` and `</h2>` to fetch the text `UEFA Europa League Highlights`. Same for `<h3>` and `<span` to fetch the text `Highlights of all matches in 
the UEFA Europa League.`. How I can do that?

Comment: Please see for example in my question that I have edited.

Comment: how about using js on the client to do this?